Terminal autocomplete (tab) not completing when changing directory up one level (cd ../)
I'm a relative Linux noob: I've worked with the bash shell for quite a while via an Ubuntu install in WSL2 on a Windows 11 machine and recently took the plunge to switch over to Linux 100%. My question is about changing directories (specifically navigating up a directory) using the terminal and using the tab autocomplete feature.
Previously when I've been navigating on Ubuntu I was able to type cd .. on the command line and then press tab which would then complete the command to be cd ../. I could have sworn that when I spun up my new install (Kali Linux) that I was able to do the same thing. But now, when I try to do this (type cd .. and then press tab to get the auto complete to change it to cd ../) this is what I see instead:

For reference sake, here's the output of neofetch on my system:
OS: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling x86_64 
Host: NH50_70RA 
Kernel: 6.8.11-amd64 
Uptime: 1 day, 1 hour, 16 mins 
Packages: 3900 (dpkg) 
Shell: zsh 5.9 
Resolution: 1080x1920, 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 5.27.10 
WM: KWin 
Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: [Plasma], Vivid-Dark-Icons [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-9750H (12) @ 4.500GHz 
GPU: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q 
Memory: 6228MiB / 31813MiB 

I feel like the different behavior is due to using bash on Ubuntu and zsh on my current setup. I found this documentation on different configuration options within the .zshrc and looked through it but I wasn't able to find anything that stood out as far as what I could do to get my desired behavior. I think this is due to me not fully understanding the documentation rather than the solution not being in there.
Sorry in advance if I didn't post the right info needed or if I didn't post enough to effectively troubleshoot this. This is my first time posting a question about Linux (well, second actually. I posted in this question over in the Superuser StackExchange but have not received any insight over there so I thought I'd post over here).
If anyone would help me figure out what the best solution is to get this desired behavior I would greatly appreciate it. Optimally I'd like to be able to type cd .. at the command prompt and be able to press tab to have it autocomplete to cd ../, then if I immediately type .. and then press tab again it would autocomplete to ../ resulting with cd ../../ at the command prompt and so on, which in this example if I then pressed enter would take me up two directories from the current directory with the single command of cd ../../ having been formed and executed.
I've seen answers where others have created something like a function to be stored in the .zshrc (or .bashrc for bash) file that could be called to navigate up a certain amount of directories at once by passing a number to the function when called, IE: the function is named something like cdu for Change Directory Up and entering cdu 2 at the command prompt and pressing enter would then automatically navigate up two directories from the current directory. This is a clever way to accomplish the same thing, but I'd really like to be able to manually "chain" on however many instances of ../ by pressing .. and then tab immediately after to dynamically see the command grow until I press enter to execute the command and navigate up that many directories. I could probably cobble together a function of my own that would let me do what I want to do, but I feel there has to be a simpler way like a setting that I need to configure in the right way that will make this happen.
Thanks in advance!

Related: How can I alias `...` to `../..` in Bash? (where the currently most upvoted and accepted answer covers zsh).

By default, . and .. are not offered as completions, because it isn't very useful: you can press / instead of Tab. For ., it's more work to use completion because it's ambiguous. However, for .., Tab is less work if . isn't ambiguous.
You can include .. in completions by setting the special-dirs style to .. in your .zshrc.
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs ..

If you also want to treat . as a possible completion, set it to true:
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true


This is exactly what I was looking for. I did see the info about zstyle and the special-dirs in the documentation, I just didn't know how to apply it. But it did feel like that was what would be related to the solution, hence what motivated me to post my question. Using this in my .zshrc file provides the expected results, and works well with my global alias I mentioned in my other comment. I will probably use the magic-dot function from the other answer, but I marked this as accepted and upvoted because this is what I envisioned as a solution when I posted the question. THANK YOU!!

The crux of the issue here is that . and .. are never expanded by globs and never offered as file name completion (though see the special-dirs zstyle in Gilles' answer) as it would generally not be useful (and even often harmful; several other shells (including bash for globs) are now also taking that path).
So in cd ..Tab, because .. is not among the list of valid completions, it is not completed, and / is not added.
Here, you could however do:
zstyle ':completion::complete:cd:*' accept-exact '(*/|)..'

For .. (or anything/..) to be accepted nevertheless in completions to cd without needing to add it as a possible completion (use :completion::complete:* for it to apply for other commands).
But a possibly better approach could be that described at my answer to How can I alias `...` to `../..` in Bash? where . is bound to a custom widget that makes so that each . added after .. or whatever/.. turns into ../.. or whatever/../.. so you just need to press . in sequence rather than ..Tab with your approach.
magic-dot() {
  if (( NUMERIC )) && [[ $LBUFFER = (|*[[:blank:]/:]) ]]; then
    LBUFFER+=..
    (( NUMERIC-- ))
  fi
    
  if [[ $LBUFFER = (|*[[:blank:]/]).. ]]; then
    repeat ${NUMERIC-1} LBUFFER+=/..
  else
    zle self-insert
  fi
}
zle -N magic-dot
bindkey . magic-dot
bindkey -M isearch . self-insert

If in emacs mode, .. followed by Alt+4,. makes it ../../../../.. for instance (/.. appended 4 times) using the usual NUMERIC prefix handling.
See also my answer to Function to go forward one directory, if possible? for another (even quicker, though limited to cd) approach at navigating the directory tree up and down.

I really, REALLY love this magic-dot function, which is what I will probably use going forward. I also very much appreciate the explanation and the first suggested solution using the zstyle setting. I neglected to mention that I use this in conjunction with a global alias so your zstyle solution kind of gives me mixed results when using it. Again though, that magic-dot function is amazing and will probably be what I end up using. That all being said, @Giles 'SO-stop being evil's answer is more along the lines of what I was trying to accomplish, so I marked that as accepted. Still upvoted!
